# Rust - Finding out correct build target

Tags: rust

I am trying to find correct build target for CradlePoint IBR200 router:
https://cradlepoint.com/product/endpoints/ibr200/

System info from python program looks like this:

```
System Linux 4.4.100-coconut+. 
Platform Linux-4.4.100-coconut+-mips-with-libc1
Machine mips
Architecture ('32bit', '')
```

I have tried compiling with target `mips-unknown-linux-gnu` and linker `mips-linux-gnu-gcc` but the executable will not run on the system

How can I determine correct target / linker?

Comment: Can you detail the error you get when you try to run it?

Comment: What version libc does your system have? That's most likely your issue. Also maybe try mips-unknown-linux-uclibc

Comment: @rodrigo Error I am getting is
```cpshell: ./main: line 1: ELF�8b@�Q9@8: not found```

Comment: @Carson How do I find out the version of libc I have?

Comment: @stkxchng run `ldd --version` and you will get a version string. On my system it looks like `ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.33-1)`

Comment: Getting `ldd: not found `
Operating system is `NetCloud OS (NCOS)`, kernel is linux but standard CLI tools do not seem available

Comment: @stkxchng oh wow, you're on something weird. does `find / -type f -name 'libc.so*'` work? Iff so, what does `<that filename> -version` display

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243599/discussion-between-carson-and-stkxchng).

Comment: The error you are getting seems to imply that it is trying to run the program as if it was a script of some kind. Btw suggest editing your question to show the error you get when running it